# ERROR: relation "domain_event_entry" does not exist [AXON]

Tags: postgresql, axon

This problem occurred while learning AXON 3.x. Using postgre 42.5.0 DB.

```
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into domain_event_entry (event_identifier, meta_data, payload, payload_revision, payload_type, time_stamp, aggregate_identifier, sequence_number, type, global_index) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2022-11-02 11:05:28.189  WARN 15368 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2022-11-02 11:05:28.189 ERROR 15368 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "domain_event_entry" does not exist
  Position: 13
2022-11-02 11:05:28.191  INFO 15368 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
```

I think the relevant tables should be created automatically. What is wrong with the configuration？

Answer (score 0):

Given you current explanation, there's not that much to go off, @zzz.
I do have two pointers for you, though:

1. Please move to the latest Axon Framework release. Axon Framework is currently on 4.6.2, which is about 4 years ahead from the latest minor release of Axon Framework 3.
2. The main thing missing from your question, is *how* you're configuring your application. Surely there's something wrong, but pinpointing what it is, is rather tough without knowing what you're doing. On this note though, if you *are* in a Spring Boot environment, adding the `axon-spring-boot-starter` dependency should be sufficient.

What might be an easy stepping stone for you, @zzz, is using AxonIQ's Initializr. Through the initializr, you can construct a basic Axon Framework application, allowing you to add several dependencies you may need as well.
You can find the initializr [here](https://start.axoniq.io/), by the way.